# R - deconvoluting complex intervals into position & location information

Tags: r, position, location, intervals

This question is an extension of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626354/r-deconvoluting-intervals-into-position-information).

There is now an additional column in `fileA` that needs to be taken into account when extracting position information from the interval. For instance, in the example below, positions 123-78000 at location X are labelled `romeo` whereas the same positions 123-78000 at location Y are labelled `mario`:

```
location  start     end      value    label
X         123       78000    0        romeo    #value 0 at positions X(123 to 77999 included).
X         78000     78004    56       romeo    
X         78004     78005    12       romeo    #value 12 at position X(78004).
X         78006     78008    21       juliet   
X         78008     78056    8        juliet  
Y         123       78000    1        mario    #value 1 at positions Y(123 to 77999 included).
Y         78000     78004    24       mario    
Y         78004     78005    4        mario    #value 4 at position Y(78004).
Y         78006     78008    12       luigi   
Y         78008     78056    14       luigi
```

On the other hand `fileB` defines the intervals that actually interest me:

```
location  start     end      label
X         77998     78005    romeo
X         78007     78012    juliet
Y         77998     78005    mario
Y         78007     78012    luigi
```

The labels in `fileA` were originally pulled in from `fileB`, so it is safe to assume that the labels are always equivalent for overlapping intervals.

I am trying to extract the information for all the individual positions in `fileA` that correspond to the intervals in `fileB` – a process which I will call deconvolution for lack of a better word. This time, I would like to do that *while at the same time taking location into account* - it's dangerous to extract location back from position as the same position numbers may appear in several locations. The output `fileC` should come up like this:

```
location  position  value   label
X         77998     0       romeo
X         77999     0       romeo
X         78000     56      romeo
X         78001     56      romeo
X         78002     56      romeo
X         78003     56      romeo
X         78004     12      romeo   
X         78007     21      juliet
X         78008     8       juliet
X         78009     8       juliet
X         78010     8       juliet
X         78011     8       juliet
Y         77998     1       mario
Y         77999     1       mario
Y         78000     24      mario
Y         78001     24      mario
Y         78002     24      mario
Y         78003     24      mario
Y         78004     4       mario   
Y         78007     12      luigi
Y         78008     14      luigi
Y         78009     14      luigi
Y         78010     14      luigi
Y         78011     14      luigi
```

I thought I would be able to implement this myself from the solution to my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21626354/r-deconvoluting-intervals-into-position-information), but I am stuck, especially on this part, I don't know how I can incorporate the location information to the position information:

```
# create sequence of positions
s <- unlist(apply(B, MARGIN=1, FUN=function(x) seq(x[2], as.numeric(x[3])-1)))
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to produce your sample output.

```
# It is essential that there be NO FACTORS
A<-read.table("fileA.txt",header=T,stringsAsFactors=F)
B<-read.table("fileB.txt",header=T,stringsAsFactors=F)

# build template with position in the appropriate ranges
template <- do.call(rbind,lapply(1:nrow(B),
                    function(i) cbind(location=B[i,]$location, 
                                      position=seq(B[i,]$start,B[i,]$end-1), 
                                      label=B[i,]$label)
))
template <- data.frame(template, stringsAsFactors=F)
# add position column to A, return as C
C <- merge(A,template,by=c("location","label"),all=T)

is.between <- function(x,low,hi) return(x>=low & x<=hi)
C <- C[is.between(C$position,C$start,C$end-1),]
C <- C[,c("location","position",value="value","label")]
C
#    location position value  label
# 1         X    78007    21 juliet
# 7         X    78008     8 juliet
# 8         X    78009     8 juliet
# 9         X    78010     8 juliet
# 10        X    78011     8 juliet
# 11        X    77998     0  romeo
# 12        X    77999     0  romeo
# 20        X    78000    56  romeo
# 21        X    78001    56  romeo
# 22        X    78002    56  romeo
# 23        X    78003    56  romeo
# 31        X    78004    12  romeo
# ...
```